# Reduce a multi-digit to one-digit -guidance not answer please

Tags: javascript, function, loops, root, repeat

goal: take a number like 54321, add the numbers together (5+4+3+2+1 = 15), then take that number (15) add the digits (1+5 = 6), so return 6;

here is my code:

```
function digital_root(n) {

 if (n >=10) {
  var digits = n.toString().split('').map(function(item, index) {return parseInt(item)}).reduce(function(a,b){ return a+b});
   console.log(digits);
 } 
}

digital_root(1632)
```

Can't figure out: How to get that function to repeat over and over until digits is just one number (i.e. less than 10). I have tried a variety of nested functions, but can't seem to get it right.

If possible please point me in the direction to the solution ("try a nesting in a while... or read up on..."), but don't give me the complete code solution ("Use this code chunk:...."). I've developed a bad habit of just reading and copying...

Thank you!

Comment: My first suggestion for a non-expert would be to get rid of the `map`.  Map is often conceptually challenging even for someone with lots of experience.  Instead try an explicit loop, where when finding digits you need to use '/10' and '%10'.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try and nix the map and work it out in a loop as you suggest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion to solve this.
Write a function `makeSingleDigit`, which argument will be your number.
You need a base condition with the base step, which in your case stops the recursion when received number is one-digit and returns the number. 
If condition is not true,  you just need to get another digit from the number by `n%10` and sum it with the `makeSingleDigit(Math.floor(n/10))`. By this, you repeatedly sum digits of new numbers, until function receives one-digit number.

*Mathematical solution just for your information:  the number, which you want to find is `n % 9 === 0 ? 9 : n % 9`, thus it is the remainder of the division by 9 if it is not 0, otherwise it is 9.*

Answer (score 2):

Try this: reference [HERE](http://www.programsformca.com/2011/09/adding-digits-in-number-to-reduce-it-to.html)

```js
function digital_root(n) {

    var singlesum = 0;
    while (n >= 10 ) {
                 singlesum=0;
        while (n > 0) {
            var rem;
            rem = n % 10;
            singlesum = singlesum + rem;
            n = parseInt(n / 10);
        }
        n = singlesum;
    }
  
  console.log(singlesum);
}

digital_root(1632)
```

Comment: Thank you the link's chart definitely put visually what I was trying to map in my head.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very optimal solution to the problem:

```js
function digital_root(n) {
  return (n - 1) % 9 + 1;
}

const result = digital_root(1632);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how this works -- but it is a FANTASTIC solution, and should not be overlooked

Answer (score 0):

Well, not a very good solution but you can give a hit.

```
function digital_root(n) {

 if (n >=10) {
  var digits = n.toString().split('').map(function(item, index) {return parseInt(item)}).reduce(function(a,b){ return a+b});
   console.log(digits);
   return(digits);
 } 
}
var num = 1632;
do{
num = digital_root(num);
}while(num>10);
```